# how to work with compass and sass in ruby?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, compass-sass

I am new to ruby. even before using i don't no how it work and use, can you help me how it works and use it, how to create project and files in that css, sass and compass and how it build the one file and use to html file .. please suggest .. ?

Answer (score 0):

Compass helps you to easily compile SASS (.scss) files into CSS. A main introduction how to install Compass is on the offical Compass-Website itself: http://compass-style.org/install/

When you succesfully installed Compass to your ruby Gems, the easiest way to create a simple SASS Project is by using your command line tool (eg. Terminal) go to the directory you want to have your project installed and enter "compass init".

Now you have to make sure that compass compiles your sass files into normal css files when you save them by running "compass watch" in your command line tool.

Everytime you edit and save a .scss file from your sass folder while "compass watch" is still running, it generates a .css file under the same name in the "stylesheets" folder.

Link to that .css file on your html file.